# "ReferenceError: angular is not defined" with code that was already used before successfully

Tags: javascript, angularjs, referenceerror

I get "ReferenceError: angular is not defined". The funny thing is, I copied the structure of my app from another working Webapp I made and just changed the names so far, I have no idea what I may have changed that causes trouble now.

I double checked the order of the script tags and tried every other solution I found but nothing's worked so far.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" ng-app="VetCare">
<head>
    <title>Vet &amp; Care Webapp</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' />

    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Vet & Care">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="redirect()">
    <div ng-view autoscroll="true"></div>
</div>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And my module and MainCtrl in app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('VetCare', ['ngCookies', 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$cookies', '$window', function($scope, $cookies, $window) {

    $scope.redirect = function () {
        //some code
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried moving the scripts from `<head>` to above the `app.js` at the end of `body`?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

If that doesn't help, do you get the correct response from loading `angular.min.js` in network tab in developer tools ?

Comment: Thanks, moving everything to the bottom worked. Though I'm still confused because my other webapp had this order and it worked... Strange

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your scripts to the bottom of your body.

When angular.min.js is loaded, angular walks the DOM and bootstraps the ng-app. In this case your dom is empty when angular walks your DOM.

By having your scripts at the bottom of the body block, angular will walk the DOM and bootstraps the app when the DOM is ready.

It'll also optimize the loading of your webpage by rendering the page while the JS files are being downloaded.